# How to understand this weird crashlytics error?

Tags: flutter, firebase, crashlytics

[image]

The error is `Attempt to invoke interface method 'void h.a.c.a.c.c(java.lang.String, h.a.c.a.c$a)' on a null object reference`

I can't find anything online that resembles this sort of issue. All my other Android errors are getting reported normally with readable stacktraces.

Is there something I'm missing to be able to get better reporting?

[image]

Comment: Does your app crash when you close the app with the back button? Can you try to reproduce it?

Comment: @OzanTaskiran Yes it does! How were you able to deduce that?

Comment: Are you using any of these "--split-debug-info" and "-obfuscate"? The latest Crashlytics Flutter SDK now support these flags, it may help you get deobfuscated reports. https://firebase.google.com/support/releases#crashlytics-flutter-symbolication-support